# How to get Facebook friends birthday?

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve Facebook friends birthday. I can't find any solution in v2, because many permissions were removed (`friends_*`). So how will I get friends information now?

Comment: can you provide any code?

Answer (score 3):

As the `friends_birthday` permission has been removed, we can't get friends birthday anymore.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

And it's not possible either to get that information outside of the API.

Comment: So theres no way to get friends birthday ?